# How to insert multiple record in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 variables, here we go:

```
@name = array('a','b','c');
@age = array('1','2','3');
```

And then I want to insert into column `name` value `a` and column `age` value `1` and loop until the end of the array.

I tried using this but non sense:

```
    $t = count($name);
    DB::table('users')->insert(array(
        for ($i=0; $i < $t ; $i++) { 
        }
    array('name' => $name.$i, 'dob' => $dob.$i)
    ));
```

How do i fix it??

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
$name = 'whatever name - ';
$age = 'whatever age - ';

foreach(range(1,3) as $i)
{ 
    DB::table('users')->insert(
        array('name' => $name.$i, 'dob' => $dob.$i)
    ); 
}
```

Or, having your arrays:

```
$names = array('a','b','c'); 
$ages = array('1','2','3');

foreach($names as $name)
{ 
    foreach($ages as $age)
    { 
        DB::table('users')->insert(
            array('name' => $name, 'age' => $age)
        ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not inserting multiple rows, its just sigle row one bye one

Answer (score 0):

```
    if u want to insert
    name age 
    a     1
    b     2
    c     3
like this then use following code

  $names = array('a','b','c'); 
  $ages = array('1','2','3');

     foreach($names as $index => $name)
     {
        $data=array('name' => $name, 'age' => $ages[$index]);
        DB::table('users')->insert($data);

     }

  if u want to insert
    name age 
    a     1
    a     2
    a     3
    b     1
    b     2
    b     3
    c     1
    c     2
    c     3
like this then use following code
 $names = array('a','b','c'); 
  $ages = array('1','2','3');

     foreach($names as $name)
     {
        foreach($ages $age){
         $data=array('name' => $name,'age' => $age);
        DB::table('users')->insert($data);
       }

     }
```

Comment: Its not inserting multiple rows, its just sigle row one bye one

Comment: i add single row also multi row

Answer (score 0):

Create array of array of data :

```
$data = array();
foreach($names as $index => $name)
{
    $item = array('name' => $name, 'age' => $ages[$index]);
    array_push($data,$item);

 }

Users::insert($data); // Eloquent
OR
DB::table('users')->insert($data); //Insert all rows
```